# How to run a search for any movie using the Rotten Tomatoes API?

Tags: php, rotten-tomatoes

Could anyone help me to create search for movies using PHP when connecting to the [Rotten Tomatoes API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/)?

On the Rotten Tomatoes site they give you example code how to get content for specific movie like so:

```
<?php
$apikey = 'insert_your_api_key_here';
$q = urlencode('Toy Story'); // make sure to url encode an query parameters

// construct the query with our apikey and the query we want to make
$endpoint = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=' . $apikey . '&q=' . $q;

// setup curl to make a call to the endpoint
$session = curl_init($endpoint);

// indicates that we want the response back
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// exec curl and get the data back
$data = curl_exec($session);

// remember to close the curl session once we are finished retrieveing the data
curl_close($session);

// decode the json data to make it easier to parse the php
$search_results = json_decode($data);
if ($search_results === NULL) die('Error parsing json');

// play with the data!
$movies = $search_results->movies;
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($movies as $movie) {
  echo '<li><a href="' . $movie->links->alternate . '">' . $movie->title . " (" . $movie->year . ")</a></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';


?>
```

I'm an beginner with PHP so an example would be great. I have manage to solve this with JavaScript but the server I have to host the page won't display it because of updates. So now I will have to turn to PHP because it displays the code from above too.

Comment: Can you outline exactly what you are having trouble with? Have you tried running this example to see if it works? Add in your key and give it a go, to start with. Bear in mind that asking for examples without a corresponding attempt tends to garner down/closevotes, so it usually best to give it a go first, and then present _actual_ code you're stuck on.

Comment: Yes of course I have tryed it with a key and it works of course. But I have no idea how to do this if I want a search bar to search any kind of movie

Comment: You'll need a `<form>` to capture the data, set the `method` to `get` and the `action` to the same pathname as your script (e.g. `search-movies.php`) and then use an `input type="text"` control to get the film name, and a `input type="submit"` to submit the search. From there, you can extract the text and feed it to the above script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form with a text field. Name the field q so it will work with your sample code.
Have the form post to the url of your sample php script.
Remove this line:

```
$q = urlencode('Toy Story');
```

Replace it with this:

```
$q = urlencode($_POST['q']);
```

That should get you started.

Note that no effort is made to sanitize the $_GET. I am just providing the basics you need to have a search form running based on the example code you posted.

If you do not know how to create a form, here is a link to a tutorial:

```
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php
```